# What does it mean to SELECT a number?

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, database-design, tree

I'm looking at an example in my book, *SQL Antipatterns*. The example table is

```
         TreePaths
==============================
    ancestor | descendant
------------------------------
       1          1
       1          2 
       1          3
       1          4
       1          5
       1          6
       1          7
       2          2
       2          3
       3          3
       4          4
       4          5
       4          6
       4          7
       5          5
       6          6
       6          7
       7          7
```

and query I'm confused about it

```
INSERT INTO TreePaths (ancestor, descendant)
   SELECT t.ancestor, 8
   FROM TreePaths AS t
   WHERE t.descendant = 5
 UNION ALL
   SELECT 8,8
```

So let me first undersand the sub-query

```
SELECT t.ancestor, 8
FROM TreePaths AS t
WHERE t.descendant = 5
```

This should return

```
t.ancestor  |   ???? 
---------------------
   5              ?
   5              ?
   5              ?
```

I thought

```
SELECT x, y
```

meant that `x` and `y` are names or columns, and `8` is not a name of a column. What the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, they really just represent the number, these are literals. Since you tagged MySql, you can check it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/literals.html).

So the subquery would return

```
t.ancestor  |   8 
---------------------
   1              8
   4              8
   5              8
```

Taking the UNION in the account, it would return

```
t.ancestor  |   8 
---------------------
   1              8
   4              8
   5              8
   8              8
```

Comment: And then `SELECT 8,8` just returns ... what, exactly?

Comment: It will return only values 8,8.. in number of rows that would depend on the where clause. If you would run `SELECT 8,8 FROM TreePaths AS t
WHERE t.descendant = 5` you would get three rows with two values, 8,8

Comment: Ah, I thought the `WHERE` clause only applied to the subquery it appears in. I'm thinking of this as two separate queries, (1)  `SELECT t.ancestor, 8 FROM TreePaths AS t WHERE t.descendant = 5` and (2) `SELECT 8,8`, whose resulting rows are then combined with `UNION ALL`. Is that not right?

Comment: yeah, that is right :) I just put that condition as an example to demonstrate how many records you would get

Answer (score 1):

`x` and `y` are *expressions* which are evaluated once for each row in the table, and whose values are taken to be the corresponding columns in the current row. `8` is also an expression, *evaluated once for each row,* whose value is taken to be the constant "8".

In this case, the query will return

```
t.ancestor   |   8
------------------
  1              8
  4              8
  5              8
```

as scaisEdge observed.

Answer (score 0):

in this case the query should return

```
t.ancestor   |   8
------------------
  1              8
  4              8
  5              8
```

you are select t.ancestor where descendant is = 5